# Android media player returns IllegalStateException

Tags: android, media-player

I have following code to play small audio files

```
private void playVoice() {

     if (mPlayVoice != null) {
         if (mPlayVoice.isPlaying()) {
             mPlayVoice.release();
             mPlayVoice = null;
         }
     }
     mPlayVoice = 
         MediaPlayer.create(BirdsActivity.this, mSoundIds[getCurrentIndex()]);
     mPlayVoice.start();
 }
```

It works fine in Samsung galaxy tab but gives  below error in small device(I Checked in Sony xperia mini pro my project)

```
08-17 12:45:45.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6639): java.lang.IllegalStateException
    08-17 12:45:45.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6639):     at   android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
    08-17 12:45:45.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6639):     at           com.android.mds.kidsapps.alphakids.BirdsActivity.playVoice(BirdsActivity.java:146)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
 PlayVoice.release();
```

Do you not mean

```
 mPlayVoice.release();
```

If you have other issues this is the best document to consult:

[Android MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

*EDIT*

Ok if you are here: [isPlaying() Invalid States](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) it show's you're trying to call isPlaying() while the player is in the error state. So you need to work out why it is *already* in the error state.

> In general, some playback control operation may fail due to various reasons, such as unsupported audio/video format, poorly interleaved audio/video, resolution too high, streaming timeout, and the like.

Have a look at adding an error listener: [setOnErrorListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29)

Comment: Actually that was not the problem.. it happened during posting the question

Comment: So what is line 146 in BirdsActivity?

Comment: in my case i'm setting `videoView.sestOnPreparedListener(.....)` and getting `mediaPlayer` in `onPrepared`, now i have global mediaplayer object, so i'm doing something like `globalM = mp`(this is my requirement) and then setting volume in that `globalMp` and getting `IllegalStateException`(but not everytime), whats the problem, should i have to set `globalMp.prepare...`, even i'm getting it from `videoView`'s prepare listener?

Answer (score 10):

Use the following code as i was facing the same exception.

```
try {
    if(mPlayVoice!=null && mPlayVoice.isPlaying()) {
        Log.d("TAG------->", "player is running");
        mPlayVoice.stop();
        Log.d("Tag------->", "player is stopped");
        mPlayVoice.release();
        Log.d("TAG------->", "player is released");
    }
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

Here write whatever you want to do. Actually the condition checking like `isPlaying()` or checking for null generates the IllegalStateException.....

Answer (score 2):

**You may have to clear the audioGroup joined with audioStream. Mine worked with the following code:**

```
public static void audioPlayCaptureStop()
        {

            try 
            {
                 if(audioStream.isBusy()) 
                 {
                     audioGroup.clear();
                     audioStream.release();
                     System.out.println("audioStream released");
                 }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("audioStream release exception: "+e.toString());
            }
        }
```